# Unit tests as Cucumber acceptance tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, cucumber, bdd, acceptance-testing

We've got our application unit tested and there are two system tests using Robot verifying the basic functionality. There is also a bunch of requirements (acceptance tests) from business as .feature files in Gherkin that we run using Cucumber.

We started implementing them as integration tests using rest assured - everything was fine for the basic functionality. The problem is with implementing the more detailed scenarios - some things that we need to verify are not persisted in DB or returned by the endpoint.

It would be really easy to test that functionality by implementing those scenarios as unit tests but I'm not sure if that is a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

I think there needs to be a back-and-forth between yourselves and the business. You'll usually end up with a couple of integration tests to prove the feature works end-to-end in a happy path/negative scenario, but you won't go through all the edge cases since that is costly (time-consuming, especially when running the integration tests). That's what the unit tests are for, covering every scenario. Convey that to the business and they might learn to trust your judgement instead of implementing each and every one of the acceptance criteria as an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

> It would be really easy to test that functionality by implementing those scenarios as unit tests but I'm not sure if that is a good practice?

If they're not implemented, it's definitely a good practice to do so as soon as possible, but, I'd pay attention to the test's scope. I also see no problem in using Cucumber to aid your unit testing effort, but don't fall into the mistake of making your unit tests bigger scope acceptance tests. Keep them as direct as possible.

You mention the complexity of some of these scenarios:

> some things that we need to verify are not persisted in DB or returned by the endpoint

Then the code should probably be more testable/maintainable on different levels. You can achieve this with some techniques. Depending on the language you use, you could use a tool similar to [mockito spy](http://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy) to spy object's interactions that otherwise, you have no way of checking, but, it's only wise to do so on appropriate test scope, like with Unit and Mock tests.

Also, consider that it's perfectly fine if you cover different parts of a given flow with different test levels. Ideally, you'll cover most of it with unit tests.

You can keep the most complex unit parts covered with unit tests, and still maintain the higher level acceptance scenarios business asks you to but don't do deep assertions in the tests.

Answer (score -1):

I interpret your question as "Is it ok to use unit tests at the same time as you use BDD?"

My take is that these are two techniques that complement each other. If something is easier using one technique, then use that technique in that particular case.

Use whatever that supports your delivery of working software. Working software is the goal, not using a specific tool.

Comment: That's not what I meant. My question is "is it ok to have unit tests as part of the acceptance tests suite" which basically boils down to "must acceptance tests be black box tests"?. If a single unit is solely responsible for one of the business requirements is it ok to test it in isolation or should we test the whole application anyway?

Comment: Then is my answer yes. It is OK to have a single unit test to guarantee the existence of a specific property. Your issue is now transformed into a trust issue. Does your stakeholders trust that the single unit test, a test they probably can't validate, will ensure that this property always hold as true. If they are happy with this situation, then go ahead and use it.